# Linux sorting the files seperated with '|' character

Tags: linux, sorting

I am having troubles with sorting in the Linux. First time evr using it. So I have file named testfile with the following info:

```
AAA BBB  | 45
Jake     | 36
Sam Sam  | 40
```

How can I sort testfile by the numeric value? I have tried to use this:

```
sort -k 2n tesfile
```

But it did not helped tried to cut the file till the '|' character and then sort also did not helped. I also tried -t key in sort, but seems like it does not work too.

```
sort -t"|", -k 1n testfile
```

Answer (score 2):

The command you need is:

```
sort -t '|' -k2 testfile
```

> -t, --field-separator=SEP

-k allows you to sort via a a specific key, which is the column in this case, so you tell it to sort by the second column in a "|"-delimited file.